# Slide Function jQuery

Tags: jquery, slide

The following jQuery creates a slide down function for my menu:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.skip-link.skip-nav').click(function(){
jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
});
});
```

However it currently just pops up, rather than slides down. How do I add a 'slide' function to this?
UPDATE:

I tried this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.skip-link.skip-nav').click(function(){
jQuery('#header-nav').slideToggle(500);
jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
});
});
```

Which works in the opposite way (the toggle I previous had shows a 'x' when closed and the hamburger when opened). This should be the opposite.

CSS code:

```
.skip-link.skip-nav span {
   display: block;
   position: absolute;
   height: 3px;
   width: 30%;
   border-radius: 9px;
   opacity: 1;
   left: 0;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out; 
   transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}


.skip-link.skip-nav span:nth-child(1) {
   top: 0px;
   background: #ccc;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav span:nth-child(2),.skip-link.skip-nav span:nth-child(3) {
   top: 10px;
   background: #ccc;
}


.skip-link.skip-nav span:nth-child(4) {
   top: 21px;
   background: #ccc;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav.open span:nth-child(1) {
   top: 18px;
   width: 0%;
   left: 50%;
   background: #000;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #000;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background: #000;
}

.skip-link.skip-nav.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  background: #000;
} 

.skip-link.skip-nav .label {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="skip-links">
            <a href="#header-nav" class="skip-link skip-nav">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
                <span class="icon"></span>
                <span class="label">MENU</span>
            </a>
</div> </div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this isn't readable? It is indented.

Comment: I gave it a few more indents for you...!? Not sure how that wasn't "readable" though.

Comment: Just re-read that and realized it came across rude, didn't mean for it to be. I'm just looking for people to "help" rather than criticize. Not sure why my question was marked down 2; if you can't help, leave it for someone who can. Marking me down just gets me kicked out. Not sure what's wrong with my question; it seems a legitimate problem and i'm no expert in jQuery so I came here hoping someone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if we could see your HTML.  I think all you need is to use jQuery's `slideDown()` method:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.skip-link.skip-nav').click(function(){
    jQuery('#header-nav').slideDown(500);
    //jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');//try it without this first
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. The first didn't work.. the second (with the 'open') acted normal upon first click, then when clicked again it did the slide-down transition (when it should be closing). More clicks and nothing happens - it won't close and won't do the slide motion. Very will. Will try adding my code now; my site is Magento based so the coding is a little confusing.